# How to buffer read/write data as a module

Tags: android, c++, kernel, driver

The issue is, this patch is not available to end users  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67406
Also, AT&T is taking their time.
the patch states "It is not enough to align the read buffer only"

There is a read/write buffer error going on here.

I cannot change the kernel drivers, this must be a non kernel related patch because at&t AND verizon block kernel level repairs.
see:
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/77054/softbricked-sgh-i337-att-with-4-4-2-ota-update

Surely I can map this process and buffer it correctly at an end user level.
I know c++, don't be shy with possible solutions.

The ultimate error is: No card detected
How do I unbork this at the end user level? Nothing kernel level will work, unless your name is AT&T...

Comment: Can you edit your post to show a minimal example?

Comment: @Thomas Matthews  I wish I was there brother. This was a 'tool question'. Digging for the right place to be.

Comment: The issue you link talks about O_DIRECT not being supported in Android 4.4 open() calls so you can avoid the file cache.  The only option I can see is writing enough data to flush the cache.

Comment: @brian beuning I understand that I need to avoid the cache, but I don't follow you about "writing enough data to flush the cache", can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot edit the kernel on the Samsung Galaxy 5 because of a proprietary 'blacklist' on the partition. You get your bad news when you try and flush the ROM with Odin.
This applies to verizon and at&t